# error adding multiple map markers on python folium from python pandas array but there's only one marker visible on the map?

Tags: python, pandas, folium

using **folium** and **Geopy** library I tried to add **multiple markers** on the map for multiple locations but the resulting map contains only **one marker for just the first location**

```
import pandas
import folium
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

GeoLocator = Nominatim(user_agent="shopLocator")
data = pandas.read_csv("supermarkets.csv")
# load the data

data["fullAddress"] = data["Address"]+", "+data["City"]+", "+data["State"]
data["GeoLocation"] = data["fullAddress"].apply(GeoLocator.geocode)
# get the full address and then the location using Geopy

data["lat"] = data["GeoLocation"].apply(
    lambda x: x.latitude if x != None else None)
data["lon"] = data["GeoLocation"].apply(
    lambda x: x.longitude if x != None else None)
# the location are ready to be used 

data.drop("fullAddress", axis=0)
# Delete the fullAddress column 

Map = folium.Map(location=None)

# using a loop to mark all location

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    folium.Marker([data.iloc[i]["longitude"],
                   data.iloc[i]["latitude"]]).add_to(Map)

Map.save("Shop_map.html")
```

Comment: can you share a sample from the content of `supermarkets.csv` ?

Comment: sure, but I doubt that it's the error source because Geopy can retrieve
`ID,Address,City,State,Country,Name,Employees
1,3666 21st St,San Francisco,CA 94114,USA, Madeira,8
2,735 Dolores St,San Francisco,CA 94119,USA,Bready Shop,15
3,332 Hill St,San Francisco,California 94114,USA,Super River,25`